# replace single quotes in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the following string BUT without the quotes around NULL. Quotes in first element of list should remain there. I am using Python 3. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
[['x', '1.1', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '3.1', '4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4'], [2.5, 2.8, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2.3, 'null', 2.6, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2, 'null', 'null', 1.8, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2, 'null', 'null', 'null', 2.4, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [1.8, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 2.4, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.5, 'null', 'null', 'null'], [1.1, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.4, 'null', 'null'], [1.3, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.4, 'null'], [1.7, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.8]]
```

Comment: If you only unquote the elements, you'll get a syntax error as `null` is not a valid keyword. Also, please tell the world what have you tried so far.

Comment: Is this really a string, or a list of lists of numbers and strings? If it is a list, then there are no strings with `'`; the `'` is just part of the string representation.

Comment: "_following string_": there is no following string in your example. What you have is a nested list.

Comment: This is not a string; it's a list of lists of strings and floats.  We're not clear on what you want for output, as Python forces quotation marks around string output as part of the standard rendering.  You've neglected to show us exactly what output you want.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: i created a string from the original list using str method . @tobias_k

Comment: @entropy Why? As a list it would be much easier than first converting to string and then manipulating the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace`:

```
   yourstring = "[['x', '1.1', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '3.1', '4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4'], [2.5, 2.8, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2.3, 'null', 2.6, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2, 'null', 'null', 1.8, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2, 'null', 'null', 'null', 2.4, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [1.8, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 2.4, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'], [2, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.5, 'null', 'null', 'null'], [1.1, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.4, 'null', 'null'], [1.3, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.4, 'null'], [1.7, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 1.8]]"

   print(yourstring.replace("'null'", "null"))
```

But please do not try to produce json by yourself. You will write hard to read code, and probably will make some bugs. Use `json.dumps()`

Comment: on repl.it, this is not working. any other solutions ? should I try on my own machine ?